# wmctrl does not expand variables

Tags: linux, shell, wmctrl

I have a window whose window ID is `0x0100000b`. If I run

```bash
wmctrl -c 0x0100000b
```

It closes this window as expected. However, if I to

```bash
test=0x0100000b
wmctrl -c $test
```

It doesn't (on both zsh and bash). I don't know why it is happening as I was expecting to achieve the same result. That is just an MWE that sheds light on problem I am facing, which is expanding arguments with the `wmctrl` command.

Comment: Unless you have a weird value of IFS, this isn't possible. Neither `wmctrl` or any other program expands its own variables -- the shell does the expansions before it starts the program at all; the program couldn't stop variables from being expanded even if it wanted to.

Comment: Much more likely your script has hidden characters -- f/e, you may have saved it with DOS newlines, which would make it equivalent to the shell command `wmcrtl -c  0x0100000b$'\r\r'` (one CR from `test`, one CR from the line with `wmctrl`).

Comment: You can run `bash -x yourscript` to run the script with debug logging to compare the command it actually runs to the command you expect; that logging expands hidden/invisible characters to be human readable (at least, if your shell is bash -- not all versions of `sh` escape things for printing successfully -- but using `bash -x` instead of `sh -x` forces that).

Comment: (Also, make sure you're comparing apples to apples in terms of execution environment; if you're comparing a script run as a service to an interactive command run from a terminal started inside a GUI session, there are major differences in how wmctrl works between those environments that have nothing to do with variable expansion).

Comment: Did you try with `test="0x0100000b"` ?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the window ID will most likely be changed on the next time you open it.

Comment: @DrKaoliN, what difference would quotes make here? They wouldn't stop a trailing carriage return after the closing quote from being appended, since shell quoting is evaluated character-by-character; and all the characters in the string evaluate to themselves in an unquoted context.

Comment: @RubemPacelli, ... While I still encourage you to use `set -x`, by the way, another way you can write your variable's contents out is to run `declare -p test #` (the space followed by a `#` prevents any invisible CR added by your editor from messing up the `declare` command itself, by putting that invisible character in a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally `wmctrl` is expanding variables properly. I was missing an option from my part. If you want that `wmctrl` interpret window arguments by its window ID rather than its string name, you must pass the `-i` flag. From the manual:

> -i     Interpret window arguments (<WIN>) as a numeric value rather than a string name for the window. If the numeric value starts with the prefix '0x' it is assumed to be a hexadecimal number.

If you don't put this argument, you will get an unpredictable behavior when passing numeric argument.

Comment: Again, it's not wmctrl expanding variables _at all_, properly or otherwise; the shell performs the expansions before wmctrl is even started.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite odd it didn't work, the two commands should behave exactly the same.

As a workaround, try :

```
kill $(wmctrl -lp | awk '/0x0100000b/{print $3}')
```

Comment: No need for the extra `grep` ... `kill $(wmctrl -lp | awk '/0x0100000b/{print $3}')`

Comment: Things that are guesses should be comments rather than answers; if the OP doesn't give us enough details to have certainty as to the mechanism behind their problem, better to request clarification until we can _have_ such certainty. See the first bullet point ("lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem") in the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (I _strongly suspect_ that the OP's script is saved with DOS newlines, btw; if that suspicion bears out it would make the question a duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings))

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your description "the OP doesn't give us enough details" is inaccurate, it'd be better to say " the OP doesn't give us enough context".

Comment: You want to hang your hat on an argument about semantics? Context is a type of data; it's a narrower statement, which certainly doesn't refute any broader form.

Comment: The term "details" here is not incorrect, only less accurate.